# Using iterators but with same amount of loc?

Tags: c++, containers

One can loop over a list by both:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> alist{1, 2, 3};

    for (const auto& i : alist)
        cout << i << endl;

    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = alist.begin(); i != alist.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Mostly I don't use iterators because of the extra line of code I have to write, `list<int>::iterator i;`.

Is there anyway of not writing it? And still use iterator? Any new trick on newer C++ versions? Perhaps implementing my own list instead of using the one from stl?

Comment: Just `for (auto i = alist.begin(); i != alist.end(); i++)` should suffice.  In fact the range based for loop is just syntactic sugar for that.

Comment: OT: `++i` might be preferalbe.

Comment: You may implement your own container with begin() and end() methods and use range-based cycle like you do at first loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to explicitely use an iterator? Because your first loop will do it anyway, just hiding the details from you. So asking how to hide the details from the second loop is kind of redundant... you just use the first loop.

Comment: Lean, *heavily*, on `auto` if you want to avoid this.

Comment: @nvoigt How does that magic happens, in the for loop? So, guess, it will call begin() and end() someway, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mostly I don't use iterators because of the extra line of code I have to write, `list<int>::iterator i;`.

You don't need to put it in an extra line. As with every `for` loop, you can define the iterator type inside of the parentheses, unless you'll need the value outside of the loops body.

So you can also write

```
    for (list<int>::iterator i = alist.begin(); i != alist.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;
```

or

```
    for (auto i = alist.begin(); i != alist.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;
```